# NoReverseMatch at /home/ Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I'm a newcomer in Django. I'm unable to point out exactly what's wrong.

#### Error

[image: I get this error]

#### views.py

```
class DetailPost(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/PostDetail.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'MySlug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post'] = Post.objects.filter(id=kwargs['id'], slug=kwargs['MySlug'])
        post = context['post']
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('create_date__hour')
        return context
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
.
.
path('home/', Home.as_view(), name='Home'),
path('<int:id>/<str:slug>/', DetailPost.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

#### home.html

```
<div id="latestp">
    {% for item in newposts %}
        <article>
            <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
            {% if item.images.image1.url %}
                <img src="{{ item.images.image1.url }}"  class="responsive-image" alt="Smiley face"
                    title={{ item.description }}/>
            {% else %} 
                <img src="{% static 'img/noimage.png' %}" class="responsive-image" alt="Null"
                    title={{ item.description }}/>
            {% endif %}
            <p>{{ item.description|truncatewords:50 }}</p>
            <a href="{% url 'blog:detail' item.id item.slug %}" class="rm">Read More</a>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

What's the matter? Is my wrong in HTML code in a tag?

Comment: Can you confirm that all the items in the `newposts` have a valid non-empty slug?

Comment: you are not getting slug... Its empty...

Comment: Maybe 'item.id' or 'item.slug' is null in templates.

Comment: Yes, every post must have slugfield.

Comment: Please check the slug for the `Post` with id `1`. From the looks of it, it should be empty which is wrong. To check the slug, you can go to django shell, and try running `Post.objects.get(id=1).slug`.